# Exit command working for Foxit Phantom but not Foxit Reader

Tags: exit, foxit, foxit-reader

In a pdf file, in the code behind a button, I have

```
Run a JavaScript (change some form fields)
Execute a menu item, File->Save
Execute a menu item, File->Exit
```

The exit command works fine in Phantom PDF (older version, 2.2), but not in Foxit Reader (8.3, pretty recent version). Just nothing is happening there.

I also checked with an old Foxit Reader version, 3.3, and it is working as expected there.

I tried "Security" and "Trust Manager" settings, those don't improve the situation, though.

I want to close the reader when hitting the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option (both creating and executing) seems to have been removed in new versions of Foxit Reader and Foxit PhantomPDF.

Further to that, although Adobe Acrobat shows "Execute a menu item, File->Exit" as being an available option, it doesn't actually exit the application, just shows you the messagebox below and if you press OK it closes the PDF but leaves Adobe Acrobat open.

[image]

It's actually a good thing this doesn't work anymore, the document creator should not be able to trigger the viewing application on the end-users machine to quit. Trigger closing of document maybe, but definitely not the viewing application.

Comment: Generally speaking, you may be right. In my case, I used this mechanism to detect when the user is finished with doing changes to a pdf and further processing it. I will accept, since it is the only answer and also what I found elsewhere: both Acrobat and Foxit removed it a few years ago already.